# How do I reference fields in another sheet in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

If I'm in a sheet1 and I want to reference the field `A1` in the field `B2` I can set `B2` to `=A1`.
How do I do this refernce when I'm in sheet2?

Answer (score 4):

```
=Sheet1.A1
```

Documentation is at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Referencing_a_Cell_in_Another_Document.

Comment: Thanks.  This should be marked as the answer.